# VB.NET List(Of String) ("System.NullReferenceException")

Tags: vb.net

I ran into a strange problem with the **List(Of String)** bit of code that worked properly before, but is acting nutty now.

[Click **HERE** for **Bigger picture**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SZjZ.png)
[image]

The Index is declared with the **New** keyword within that same function block:

```
Dim indexs As New List(Of UInt64)
```

[image]

Those images should explain it all.

At the start of the function are the declarations, & no **Try.. Catch** blocks, just a **Do While**, & regular **If.. Else**, & **For Each** blocks. I'm confused. :(

**EDIT:**

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
       at memScan.Form1.bgScanFirst_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) 
       in Form1.vb:line 398
       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Are you sure its not `meminfo` that is null - seems more likely.

Comment: meminfo is not nothing, because that part of the code would not be reached if it was... I made sure of that. :) It's fully populated (Structure)

Comment: yep - I noticed the values in the watch window too. Are you using threading around this maybe?

Comment: What's in the part *before* `indexs.Add....`?

Comment: It is also handier (a lot!) if you post the code, instead of taking screenshots...

Comment: It is in a backgroundworker thread. The part before the indexs.Add is just some private formulas for working between 64, & 32 bit memory from a 64 bit app targeting 32, & 64 bit processes. It just checks, & verifies before proceeding.

Comment: Your problem occurs somewhere between line `294` and `397`. But it's impossible to answer if you're not willing to share the code.

Comment: From line 293 to 397, the **indexs** List(Of String) variable is not touched, also the **meminfo** structure is not accessed once populated, & is fully intact prior to entering the **For Each** block. They are not accessed from anywhere else in code, or other thread. I am starting to think it could be a VS corruption of cache, &/or data files somewhere that is related to VS's install.

Comment: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6SZjZ.png) <-- Bigger pic

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace that includes the inner exception?  Also can you post the `bgScanFirst_DoWork` source code?

Comment: True, without the code its hard to just guess whats happenning ... 

you said it was working before. So something  have been changed since. is in on tfs ? check the differences with latest version, the error might be something really stupid that you just overlook because you know the code too much to see it. Often a coworker will takes 10 seconds to spot something weird when your banging your head on it since a few hours.

Comment: Like @Styxxy said, where I am, images are blocked.

Comment: @Thierry This is so true, & is the main problem most times for me... not seeing a simple mistake, but this one is clearly showing one thing, but claiming another... seemingly un-related error message. However, maybe numerics are overflowing when accessed from the **meminfo** structure, but not shown... even though I am using UInt64 vars.

Comment: In this case the value you want to Add() to indexs is 14,042,738. It's clearly far from UInt64.MaxValue

Comment: the only guess I have : are you adding info in tempadd ( since this is a background thread ) while you are looping it ? 

the System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext() error seems to be there indicating he's trying to reach a new item of the list, but he sees it as empty. It could happens if you increase the size of tempadress while looping it.

Comment: @Thierry nothing is accessing **tmpAddresses** from any place else. I know bugs have been claimed to linger around memory P/Invokes, & 64/32 bit cross interoperability like 64 trying to access 32 mem space, & vice versa would bug out due to the P/Invoke VirtualQueryEx's lpaddress parameter being **IntPtr**, & not UInt64, or other overloads, also, accesses that parameter directly (ByRef) & strangely casts the passed var to IntPtr somehow... thus breaking everything. IntPtr auto sizes 32/64 based on OS, so can't target opposite XX bit without some manual work. So maybe List(Of X) has bugs too?

Comment: I switched back to Debug mode, & the problem went away. Clearly a bug. It might be due to temp runtime cached helper files in the debug/release folders of VS.net for the project being corrupt?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug... usually associated with project cache files for VS being corrupted, or deleted. Switching from Debug to Release, or vice versa usually resolves it temporarily.

To fully resolve, just create a new project, then copy, & paste the text code (NOT FILES) to new files of the same name (if you wish) in that new project to resemble the corrupted project, & re-run.

All should be well again. :)